# Getting error in Jenkins while deploying on Cloud Foundry on Bluemix, federated ID issue

Tags: jenkins, ibm-cloud, single-sign-on, cloud-foundry

I’m new to Jenkins. I am trying to deploy an Angular Application to Cloud Foundry on Bluemix but, with the CF plugin I am getting the failure with an error -

> Cloud Foundry Plugin: org.cloudfoundry.uaa.UaaException: unauthorized:
>   BMXLS0202E: You are using a federated user ID, please use one time
>   code to login with option --sso.

I am not sure how can I use the command `ibmcloud login  -o <org> -s <space> --sso`

Comment: Is the question about how to use the SSO option with Jenkins or about the ibmcloud CLI command? In general, the recommended way is to first login, then to set the target (org and space). https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli/reference/ibmcloud?topic=cloud-cli-ibmcloud_cli#use-one-time-passcode

Comment: @data_henrik thanks for responding. The question is related to the command **ibmcloud** and the options to login. I have tried to run the **ibmcloud** commands from the Jenkins but, the command is unrecognized by the Jenkins thus, I tried to install `ibmcloud` in runtime still the `bx` command and as well as the `ibmcloud` command not working. Any idea how to run the `ibmcloud` command from Jenkins for login to Bluemix like  `ibmcloud login  -o <org> -s <space> --apikey <myAPIKey>`. Thus the question is not exactly the SSO but, running `ibmcloud` may be with --sso or --apikey.